# How to interact with Mixcloud Widget?

Tags: vue.js, mixcloud

I have a component containing a mix cloud embed, here is the code:

```
<template>
  <div>
  <iframe id="widget" width="100%" height="60" :src="iframe.src" frameborder="0" v-show="iframe.loaded"></iframe>

 </div>
</template>
```

I've load the mixcloud widget API in the root file:

```
<script src="//widget.mixcloud.com/media/js/widgetApi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But I can't interact with the player:

```
var widget = Mixcloud.PlayerWidget(document.getElementById("widget"));
widget.pause();
```

Console says:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.mixcloud.com') does not match the recipient window's origin

Uncaught TypeError: widget.pause is not a function
```

I believe it's because the embed is loaded asynchronous.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is the code get executes `document.getElementById("widget")` with respect to Vue? It's likely the iframe with the id `widget` doesn't exist when it is executed.

Comment: Hi bert, this code is in the component

Answer (score 0):

Template:

```html
    <template>
      <div>
        <iframe
          id="mixcloud"
          :src="link"
          @load="mountApi"
          width="100%"
          height="120"
          frameborder="0"
          allow="autoplay"
        >
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Component:

```js
    <script>
    var widget

    export default {
      name: 'mixcloud',
      computed: {
        link: function () {
          // ...
          return link
        }
      },
      methods: {
        mountApi: function () {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          widget = Mixcloud.PlayerWidget(document.getElementById('mixcloud'))
        },
        play: function () {
          widget.play()
        },
        pause: function () {
          widget.pause()
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

...works fine. :)